# How to deal with downtime of web server without losing SEO ranking?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, .htaccess, http-headers, seo

I am having a website which I'm planning to keep in maintenance mode for about 2 days without losing SEO ranking. According to [Google blog post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2011/01/how-to-deal-with-planned-site-downtime.html), we can do this by having a `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` with `Retry-After` header.

I have used the following code in `.htaccess` file in the root directory (for 503).

**My problem:** How to use the Retry-After header. Can anyone help me with this?

```
ErrorDocument 503 "Our website is temporarily closed for maintenance."
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the retry-after header like this.

```
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/503.html$
Header always set Retry-After "3600"
RewriteRule .* - [R=503]
```

Here is a [blog post](http://szeryf.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/simplest-way-to-set-up-a-well-be-back-shortly-page/) for more details.